# Excel logic, count if larger than 0 (with dates)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns, each for three periods (1-11, 11-21 and 21-31 i the month). Each of these columns have a top cell with a number representing how many 0's I have in the rows below (a checklist where 1 means DONE and 0 means not done). I also have a column with dates from 1-31. Then I have three cells that tell me "# left period 1, 2 and 3". My issue is that I don't know how to get anything but #DIV/0 if the period has ended, and there are still tasks left to be done. Ie. how to say "If TODAY".

I've added an example file: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5XqxNeZQfssU19IcFhTQ1R3eG8&usp=sharing

> OLD POST:
>
> It works fine counting as long as the period has not ended, then I get
>   a '#DIV/0!'-error. Can someone help me?
>
> It looks like:
>
> Cell with "Tasks left / day Period 1":
>
> ```
>     =(K10+(N185/3))/(COUNTIF(Period1[Period
> 1];">"&TODAY()))
> ```
>
> K10 is the cell with the total of 0's for this period. N185 is tasks
>   not governed by periods, thus split by 3. Period1[Period 1] is the
>   table and column with the dates that should be counted in Period 1.
>
> Sample data:
>
> ```
>     A1
>     [formula for tasks left / day period 1 here]
> ```
>
> K10  K11 K12
> [5]  [0] [0]
>
> [1]  [1] [1]
> [0]  [1] [1]
> [0]  [1] [1]
> [1]  [1] [1]
> [0]  [1] [1]
> [0]  [1] [1]
> [0]  [1] [1]
>
> N185
> [3]
>
> [1]
> [1]
> [1]
> [0]
> [0]
> [0]
>
> Period1[Period 1] (table)
> 2016-03-04
> 2016-03-05
> 2016-03-06
> 2016-03-07
> 2016-03-08
> 2016-03-09
> 2016-03-10 </code></pre>
>
> So, if today is 15th of march, the result should be 6 in A1. Now I get
>   '#DIV/0!' as there is no date that is '>' today. With this result I'm
>   ending up pretty blind regarding any backlog.

Comment: If you are going to mashup cell references from all over the worksheet together with cell references from a ListObject (aka *structured*) table, then you had best supply sample data together with expected results. Screenshots are discouraged.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with ListObject.. but I've written out all cells involved now. Example: N185 [3] shows that there are 3 zeroes below (it's a Count - Sum, but shouldn't be relevant here as it's the number from the cell with [3] that I'm using).

Comment: The **Period1[Period 1]** reference is to a **[structured table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E)** reference. These tables are also known as ListObject tables.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation! The more of the lingo (not Macromedia Director ref.) I learn, the better I can work with excel in the future. Do you have any suggestion as of how I could achieve my task? I simply don't speak the language well enough yet to say "if <today, show all remaining"...

Comment: I spent some time trying to figure out your worksheet layout but had no success (see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxs4g.png)). I'm afraid without the correct layout, any solution is merely a shot in the dark. Consider posting a redacted copy of your workbook to a public file share like google docs and putting a link to the publically shared xlsx back here.

Comment: Uploaded: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5XqxNeZQfssU19IcFhTQ1R3eG8&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#DIV/0!` error is occurring when the number of available data to complete the tasks runs out. However, this also changes the outcome from 'to-be-done' to 'not-completed-in-time' and the divisor should reflect that.

```
=(K10+(N185/3))/MAX(COUNTIF(Period1[Period 1],">"&TODAY()), 1)
```

The above will never allow a division by less than 1 and a division by 1 does not affect the number so the numerator and quotient are the same. Similarly, the text label in A2 could be changed to a formula like,

```
=IF(MAX(Period1[Period 1])<TODAY(), "Left P1", "Left/Day P1")
```

These changes should be carried across to the formulas in B1:C2.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I like the twist with alternate text also, saves some space also (: